# Include tag Django: Pass template name as variable from AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

This is the template code in Django, where "condition_template.html" should be replaced with template name variable

```
{% include "condition_template.html" %}
```

I want to pass the condition_template_name which returned from AJAX API call response below:

```
$.ajax({
      url: get_template_data_url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
           var condition_template_name = data['condition_template_name']
      }
    });
```

Comment: In summary, what you want to do is to include a template dynamically using AJAX?

Comment: This is vulnerable to injection attacks and whatever it is your template should be refreshed to show the change and there is no point to use ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this with Django by itself without reloading the page. Template includes are handled in the backend when the server is building the page. Ajax is done after the browser has received the page. To communicated an ajax value to django to use in an include, you'd need to send it as part of a POST or GET request (respectively, using javascript to add a hidden form field for a form  or a querystring value to a url, eg, href="url?name=value", and then reload the page/view to send the value to the template via the context.

There are some third party solutions that might work without pageload. HTMX, for example, abstracts an ajax request that you can send to a django view, then receive the HTML that Django generates and place it into your currently loaded page. You could use ajax to get the appropriate view name, then javascript to alter the hx-get value with the appropriate include and trigger the exchange.